# How to position an input form at the center of a page?

Tags: css

I want to position a registration from at the center of a page.

please tell me how should i do that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Encapsulate it in a div with the following CSS attributes:

```
<div style="width:400px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; border:1px solid #000;">
    <form action="helloWorld">
        <Some markup>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: add on: use XHTML 1.0 transitional. Also to shorten it: `margin:0px auto;`

Comment: You would also need `text-align:center` on your body/div to centre it in the page correctly, it's not enough just having the margins as auto.

Comment: thanks a lot .what about the top and bottom margins ??? the above code places the form at the very top of the page /

Comment: You can do `margin: 10px auto 0 auto;` and it will do the same but with extra space at the top of the page.

Comment: You can certainly add the bottom and top margins.  It's the left and right margins that will horizontally center it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto" align=center>
 <input button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a .CSS file with the following:

```
form {width: 40%;
      margin-right: 30%;
      margin-left: 30%;
      background-color: green}

div.mainform {width:100%;
              border:1px solid #000}
```

Then in the HTML document I used.

```
<DIV ID="MAINFORM">
    <FORM>
        Other HTML Markup
    </FORM>
</DIV>
```